# find base changes with respect to angle for ladder

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> A 10 ft ladder leans against a wall at an angle θ with the
> horizontal, as shown in the accompanying ﬁgure. The top
> of the ladder is x feet above the ground. If the bottom of
> the ladder is pushed toward the wall, ﬁnd the rate at which
> x changes with respect to θ when θ = 60 ◦ . Express the
> answer in units of feet/degree.

[image]

In all of my earlier questions I had added process how I solved. But, in this question. I am unable to understand the first process. The is saying to solve $dx=d\theta$, isn't it? I have length of ladder which is 10 ft. But, I think that's not $x$. $x$x is base that's what I think. So, the question is saying to find base changes with respect to angle. Earlier in all of my question I had an equation like this $x=2a^2$(just a sample) But, this time I don't have any equation given. I was thinking to solve it using $\tan$. But, I don't know what to write in first line.

$$dx/d\theta = ?$$

Comment: Use trig to get a formula between x and $\theta$. Then, take a derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to find the rate of change of x with respect to theta(). You have an equation in hand,
i.e,
using
$$ sin=\frac{x}{10}$$
Differentiating it with respect to  we get
$$ cos=\frac{\frac{dx}{d}}{10}$$
$$ \frac{dx}{d}=10cos$$

We want to find the rate at =60 deg,so substituting it,we get,

$$\frac{dx}{d}=5 feet/deg$$

Hope it helps!!